# Apple Mach-O Errors on Build using Parse

Tags: ios, swift

I had an issue where I had four build errors when I tried to link Parse to an existing Xcode project.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge! Unfortunately your question is missing a lot of details, which the answer does not appear to address either; all they refer to is "an issue", which does not give readers a lot to go on. For example, you'll want to list the build errors that Xcode spits out, and you'll want to describe in more detail how you obtained and added the framework, what version, etc. This way a future reader will know if the problem they're facing is similar, and if so, how your answer might help them.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, drag the Bolts.framework into the Xcode project (as you dragged in the Parse framework). This will fix the issue